# How can I simulate a randomly-generated universe?

Tags: procedural-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate a universe?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13097/how-to-generate-a-universe)

Were would I start looking if I wanted to develop an engine to simulate space at random. Things like black holes, galaxies at distance and moving stars, asteroids and so on?

I would like to know if anyone has some good tips for this, or if there is some information online?

Comment: i understand Cosmology, but I'm wondering how to input it into a game. Using C# and XNA framework, I'm trying to have it auto populate stars and of course i will have to build a Physics Engine also to simulate gravity to pull in stars and stuff. But information on the Game side?

Comment: You're talking about [procedural generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_generation), the linked wikipedia page should be a good start point. See also [this stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155069/how-does-one-get-started-with-procedural-generation) question/answer.